# Undefined symbol: nominal type descriptor for Foundation.Locale.LanguageCode error

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart

Hi I'm getting this error when I run on ios device

```
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: nominal type descriptor for 
Foundation.Locale.LanguageCode

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for 
Foundation.Locale.Language

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: Foundation.Locale.language.getter : 
Foundation.Locale.Language

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: Foundation.Locale.Language.languageCode.getter : Foundation.Locale.LanguageCode?

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: Foundation.Locale.Region.identifier.getter : Swift.String

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: Foundation.Locale.LanguageCode.identifier.getter : Swift.String

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: nominal type descriptor for Foundation.Locale.Region

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for Foundation.Locale.LanguageCode

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: Foundation.Locale.region.getter : Foundation.Locale.Region?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update my macOS and Xcode to the last version and now it working